# VTK and CMake... Not able to "configure"

Tags: cmake, vtk

I have created a `VTKTest` directory containing the two files from `VTK/Examples/Tutorials/Step6/Cxx`, and another directory, namely, `VTKTestBin`

In CMake, I have specified the source as `VTKTest` and the build as `VTKTestBin`.

When I hit the `configure` button, I get an error message telling me: `error in configuration process, project files may be invalid`

How can I go around this?

Comment: Maybe you need to configure from VTK root?

Comment: Configure will tell you the problems it had. You need to take care of these.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the CMakeLists.txt file to:

```
PROJECT (Step6)

FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(Cone6 Cone6.cxx)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Cone6 ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```